# ReadAsync() issuse in IronOCR

Tags: c#, winforms, ocr

I want to convert from an image, scanned pdf file to a searchable pdf. It works fine with Read(), but the main thread will be blocked until the process is finished. So I'm using ReadAsync() to not block the main thread, but I have the error "Recognition of image failed". I don't know why, because the Read() run fine so it can't be an image quality problem. Please help me.

```
string _zPdfFilePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "File", "hdcc.pdf");
var _IronOcr = new IronTesseract();
    _IronOcr.Language = OcrLanguage.Vietnamese;

    using (var _Input = new OcrInput())
    {
        _Input.AddPdfPages(_zPdfFilePath, null, null, null);
        string _zPath = "hdcc-searchable.pdf";

        var _t1 = _IronOcr.ReadAsync(_Input, null);
        var _t2 = initializeWebViewAsync();

        Task.WhenAll(_t1, _t2).ContinueWith((_t) =>
        {
            if (Disposing || IsDisposed)
                return;

            if (_t1.IsCanceled || _t2.IsCanceled)
                return;
            else if (_t1.Exception != null)
                MessageBox.Show(_t1.Exception.InnerException.Message);
            else if (_t2.Exception != null)
                MessageBox.Show(_t2.Exception.InnerException.Message);
            else
            {
                if (InvokeRequired)
                {
                    Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
                    {
                        _t1.Result.SaveAsSearchablePdf(_zPath);

                        string _zUrl = "file:///" + Path.GetFullPath(_zPath).Replace('\\', '/');

                        if (webView != null && webView.CoreWebView2 != null)
                        {
                            webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate(_zUrl);
                        }
                    }));
                }
                else
                {
                    _t1.Result.SaveAsSearchablePdf(_zPath);

                    string _zUrl = "file:///" + Path.GetFullPath(_zPath).Replace('\\', '/');

                    if (webView != null && webView.CoreWebView2 != null)
                    {
                        webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate(_zUrl);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }`
```

Comment: You seem to have a misconception of how async works. The way you are using Task.WhenAll ("fire-and-forget") causes your code to exit the scope of "using(.. new OcrInput)" prematurely, as the result of ".ContinueWith" is not awaited. Result: the OcrInput is disposed of while .ReadAsync is still running